# pass local path to HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

I need to pass local path to HttpWebRequest in c#. i have test.xml in my c drive and i need get that xml file in `HttpWebRequest`. but it throws exception in

```
HttpWebRequest rqst = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Uri.EscapeUriString(urlServ))
```

line "Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed."

my coding->

```
string urlServ = "file:\\c:\\test.xml";
  try
   {             
      HttpWebRequest rqst = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Uri.EscapeUriString(urlServ));
      rqst.KeepAlive = false;
   }
catch{}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to get local file via HTTP? There are likely better ways to do what you actually need.

Comment: actually still not develop the server side coding and i need to check the rest of my coding is working properly.so i assume that after they develop server side coding then i'll get xml file.so till that i need to do my further work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a `file:` URI is supposed to be created with forward-slashes, not back slashes. So, use this:

```
string urlServ = "file:///c:/test.xml";
```

I noticed when I typed it into my browser with backslashes, FF converted it to forward slashes for me.

Comment: i tried these 2 uri but still give the same exception {"Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed."}

Comment: now it gives some sort of other exception -> {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'."} thanx....

Comment: Ah ha! We have the right syntax then... now it's just that HttpWebRequest can't be used for this kind of URI. Glad I could help! Please consider checking the hollow Check Mark right below the arrows and 0 up to the left there...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `WebRequest.Create(uri)` - this will automatically create the right object based on the URI type (e.g. file, http, etc). Now you can use the same code for real web pages or local test files.

I saw this in the documentation of [FileWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.filewebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Do not use the FileWebRequest constructor. Use the WebRequest.Create
>   method to initialize new instances of the FileWebRequest class. If the
>   URI scheme is file://, the Create method returns a FileWebRequest
>   object.

Comment: Thanks, it was useful for me +1